# Matching File Names from a CSV file then move those Files to a New Directory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, for-loop

I have a folder full of files, such as txt files, csv files, HTML files, pdf files. Then I have another csv file that contains the names of the files that I need from that folder. I want to move the files to another folder that match file names from the csv file "name column".

Sample file names in the folder:

```
doggy.csv
cattodog.txt
birdy.pdf
eagle.pdf
:
:
wolfy.pdf.txt.csv
```

My csv file:

```
ID  Name
001 doggy.csv
002 cattodog.txt
003 eagle.pdf
:
:
n  wolfy.pdf.txt.csv
```

I am wondering are there any fast ways to create a code that can loop through the folder that matches the "name column" from my csv file then moves those match files to another folder?

Thanks!

Comment: you can either go for `os` or `shutil` package. From my understanding it's nothing to do with pandas because it won't be vectorized.

Comment: but I will have to read my csv file into pandas then extract the name column out to match files from my folder

Comment: yeah, you are right. What i tried to say is, though you used pandas you have to either go to apply or iteration line by line. So, it won't help vectorization. I suggest you to use `csv-shutil` combination without pandas.

Comment: Thanks! @MohamedThasinah I will try to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use `pandas` to read your csv file containing the filenames and then loop through it:

```
import pandas as pd
import os, shutil

## read filenames using pandas
df_files = pd.read_csv("csvContainingFilestoMove.csv")

## set file locations
fileOrigin = "./" #file origin
fileDest="destinationPath/" #file destination

for ff in df['Name'].tolist():
    print(f"Moving file {ff}")
    shutil.move(fileOrigin+ff, fileDest) #shutil to move file
```

You can also use `if not os.path.exists(fileDest+ff)` to check if the file already exists at the destination in case you want to use `copy` instead of `move`

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

This code might help:

```
import pandas as pd 
import shutil

my_csv = pd.read_csv('my_files.csv')

file_names = my_csv.Name.tolist()


for file_name in file_names:
    shutil.move("path/to/filesfolder/".join(file_name), "path/to/newfolder/".join(file_name))
```

Also, I recommend to save your names in a txt file and mv their files with bash.

```
def save_to_txt(file_list):
    with open('file_names.txt', 'w+') as wfile:
        for file in file_list:
            wfile.write(file + '\n')
```

and then in your commandline:

```
for file in $(cat path/to/file_names.txt); do mv path/to/"$file" path/to/newfolder; done
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to use it and combine it with my existing code.